# How can I print/return values in multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

Hi I have been working on opencv-python with opencv 3.0.0 and python 2.7.x

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,25,0.01,10)

print corners
```

this is returning me

```
[[[ 335.  263.]]

 [[ 306.  254.]]

 [[ 337.  253.]]

 [[ 349.  262.]]

 [[ 507.  361.]]

 [[ 300.  264.]]

 [[ 420.  250.]]

 [[ 362.  252.]]

 [[ 375.  261.]]

 [[ 322.  254.]]

 [[ 409.  260.]]

 [[ 545.  294.]]

 [[ 505.  398.]]

 [[ 388.  252.]]

 [[ 493.  315.]]

 [[ 578.  376.]]

 [[ 480.  376.]]

 [[ 510.  375.]]

 [[ 396.  261.]]

 [[ 493.  376.]]

 [[ 532.  376.]]

 [[ 575.  357.]]

 [[ 540.  360.]]

 [[ 514.  307.]]

 [[ 401.  251.]]]
```

I know this is a multi-dimensional array and how can I print the values in this array in the form of (x,y) ? I think there is a simple answer for this but it has been quite a long time I have used python. Thanks in advance !

Comment: `corners.reshape(-1, 2)`? Or more specifically, `list(map(tuple, corners.reshape(-1, 2)))`

Comment: Can you provide your expected output, for the given data? That would help.

Comment: I just want it to be printed such as (362, 252), (375, 261), (322, 254)... and so on. Or it is actually better for me to assign this each of these values as x1, y1, x2, y2...

Comment: So the answer you ticked works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray,25,0.01,10)

corners = np.int0(corners)
for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    print(x,y)
```

Comment: Can I ask you what exactly np.int0 does? I saw it couple of times but couldn't fully understand it.

Comment: @JimmySuh It converts the `float` values to `integer` values. `int0` is same as `int32` or `int64` for `32 bit` and `64 bit` systems respectively.